# Mesh moves when parenting rig

Tags: rigging

It's not just a little. It moves by A LOT, and it's also rotated. Movements tied to nodes makes the mesh distorted. I don't understand it. It was just a normal mesh that I had applied all transforms to before rigging.

[image: Character]

[image: Rig]

Comment: There's something without transforms applied, probably in the form of a parent or parenting inverse.   Unparent mesh object and keep transform; apply all transforms on mesh object; parent mesh object to rig object.